# Globalize in Angular CLI

Tags: angular, typescript, command-line-interface, devextreme, globalize

i want to globalize my devextreme angular2 - app. However, I am unable to find usable resources on how to integrate globalize with devextreme. Are there any step - by - step tutorials or example projects I can review? I really have no clue...

Thanks,
Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the examples of using devextreme-angular with Globalize in [this](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-examples/) GitHub repo.